# c# argument out of range was unhandled due to the SelectedIndex

Tags: c#, exception, combobox, arraylist, client-server

'Argument out of range was unhandled' error occur when button is clicked due to no number or no such index number of client connected is selected. Error show to this code:

```
workerSocket = (Socket)m_workerSocketList[comboBox1.SelectedIndex];
```

i want to give a message box say 'Please select a correct number'. what should be coded to handle this error?

here is the code:

```
void indmsgbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string msg = richtxtindmsg.Text;
    msg = "Private Admin Message: " + msg + "\n";
    byte[] byData = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(msg);
    Socket workerSocket = null;
    // for (int i = 0; i < m_workerSocketList.Count; i++)

    workerSocket = (Socket)m_workerSocketList[comboBox1.SelectedIndex];

    if (workerSocket != null)
    {
        if (workerSocket.Connected)
        {
            workerSocket.Send(byData);
        }
    }       
}
```

Comment: what is the exception? how do you handle the connect/reconnect?

Comment: How do you populate `comboBox1`? It might be better to control your population of that control more elegantly instead of checking for an invalid index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try:

```
if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex > -1 && comboBox1.SelectedIndex < m_workerSocketList.Count)
{
    workerSocket = (Socket)m_workerSocketList[comboBox1.SelectedIndex];
}
else
{
    //message
}
```

Comment: -1 because this would not handle the case where the index may exceed the number of elements in `m_workerSocketList`. You would need to extend your answer to check for this case too, i.e. by adding a second conditional to your `if` statement that checks the `SelectedIndex` is below the count of `m_workerSocketList`.

Answer (score 2):

Before calling `workerSocket = (Socket)m_workerSocketList[comboBox1.SelectedIndex];` you need to check the value of `comboBox1.SelectedIndex`. If it's out of range, display your error message; only if it's in range (`>= 0` and `< m_workerSocketList.Count`) will it be safe to use as an index into `m_workerSocketList`.